# Using load() and after() togheter

Tags: jquery, load

I've got a list (.menutabs) and i want to add content loaded from a .php AFTER the list

I'm trying to use

```
$(".menuTabs").after(function() {
  $this().load("/common/header_box.php");
});
```

But it isn't working

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `after` does accept a function as a parameter, `load` is async so will not work with this pattern. You are best to use the standard `$.ajax` method's success callback. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/common/header_box.php',
    success: function(html) {
        $('.menuTabs').after(html);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `$this()`, which should be `$(this)`, refers to the element which you want to insert content after.  You would want to return a new jQuery object to load the content into.

```
$(".menuTabs").after(function() {
  return $("<div></div>").load("/common/header_box.php");
});
```

However, it is more efficient to use a single `$.ajax` call, as Rory's answer suggests.